# strtok - char array versus char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strtok wont accept: char *str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529834/strtok-wont-accept-char-str)

When using the `strtok` function, using a `char *` instead of a `char []` results in a segmentation fault.

This runs properly:

```
char string[] = "hello world";
char *result = strtok(string, " ");
```

This causes a segmentation fault:

```
char *string = "hello world";
char *result = strtok(string, " ");
```

Can anyone explain what causes this difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
char string[] = "hello world";
```

This line initializes `string` to be a big-enough array of characters (in this case `char[12]`).  It copies those characters into your local array as though you had written out

```
char string[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

The other line:

```
char* string = "hello world";
```

does not initialize a local array, it just initializes a local pointer.  The compiler is allowed to set it to a pointer to an array which *you're not allowed to change*, as though the code were

```
const char literal_string[] = "hello world";
char* string = (char*) literal_string;
```

The reason C allows this without a cast is mainly to let ancient code continue compiling.  You should pretend that the type of a string literal in your source code is `const char[]`, which can convert to `const char*`, but never convert it to a `char*`.

Comment: Many good answers, but I found this the clearest example of the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 16):

In the second example:

```
char *string = "hello world";
char *result = strtok(string, " ");
```

the pointer `string` is pointing to a string literal, which cannot be modified (as `strtok()` would like to do).

You could do something along the lines of:

```
char *string = strdup("hello world");
char *result = strtok(string, " ");
```

so that `string` is pointing to a modifiable copy of the literal.

Comment: I'm going to resist the urge to -1, but I really don't like this answer. I think it leads newbie coders to the idiom of throwing around `strdup` to solve segfaults rather than learning how to manage memory (and especially strings). But I'm not sure what a better answer would be without saying "just use the array or dynamically allocate memory for your string". By the way, `strdup` is not standard C, but of course it's easy enough to implement on systems which don't have it.

Answer (score 4):

`strtok` modifies the string you pass to it (or tries to anyway). In your first code, you're passing the address of an array that's been initialized to a particular value -- but since it's a normal array of char, modifying it is allowed.

In the second code, you're passing the address of a string literal. Attempting to modify a string literal gives undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case (`char *`), the string is in read-only memory.  The *correct* type of string constants is `const char *`, and if you used that type to declare the variable you would get warned by the compiler when you tried to modify it.  For historical reasons, you're allowed to use string constants to initialize variables of type `char *` even though they can't be modified.  (Some compilers let you turn this historic license off, e.g. with gcc's `-Wwrite-strings`.)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that, in the first case, there is an implicit copy of the string literal into the char array. Which is why you don't have the same issue.

Comment: `const char *` actually also results in a segfault if attempted to be used with `strtok`, but at least it gives a compilation warning.  But noted about the modification being the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been less telegraphic.  Answer edited.

Comment: Using `const char *` should give a compiler error, not a warning, if you pass it to `strtok`. The C language does not have implicit conversions which remove qualifiers; you need an explicit cast.

Comment: "[construct] discards qualifiers from pointer target type" really is just a warning with gcc 4.2, even with -pedantic.  It doesn't appear to be a special case for `char *` either.

Answer (score 0):

The first case creates a (non const) char array that is big enough to hold the string and initializes it with the contents of the string.  The second case creates a char pointer and initializes it to point at the string literal, which is probably stored in read only memory.

Since strtok wants to modify the memory pointed at by the argument you pass it, the latter case causes undefined behavior (you're passing in a pointer that points at a (const) string literal), so its unsuprising that it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Because the second one declares a pointer (that can change) to a constant string...

So depending on your compiler / platform / OS / memory map... the "hello world" string will be stored as a constant (in an embedded system, it may be stored in ROM) and trying to modify it will cause that error.