# difference between char* and char[] with strcpy()

Tags: c, string, char

I've been having trouble the past couple hours on a problem I though I understood. Here's my trouble:

```
void cut_str(char* entry, int offset) {
    strcpy(entry, entry + offset);
}

char  works[128] = "example1\0";
char* doesnt = "example2\0";

printf("output:\n");

cut_str(works, 2);
printf("%s\n", works);

cut_str(doesnt, 2);
printf("%s\n", doesnt);

// output:
// ample1
// Segmentation: fault
```

I feel like there's something important about char*/char[] that I'm not getting here.

Comment: This question is asked here frequently. Please see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090434/strtok-char-array-versus-char-pointer

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 11):

The difference is in that `doesnt` points to memory that belongs to a string constant, and is therefore not writable.

When you do this

```
char  works[128] = "example1\0";
```

the compiler *copies* the content of a non-writable string into a writable array. `\0` is not required, by the way.

When you do this, however,

```
char* doesnt = "example2\0";
```

the compiler leaves the pointer pointing to a non-writable memory region. Again, `\0` will be inserted by compiler.

If you are using `gcc`, you can have it warn you about initializing writable `char *` with string literals. The option is `-Wwrite-strings`. You will get a warning that looks like this:

```
 warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

The proper way to declare your `doesnt` pointer is as follows:

```
const char* doesnt = "example2\0";
```

Comment: "the compiler copies the content of a non-writable string into a writable array" -- Not quite. "example1\0" here is not a non-writable string, it is string literal -- a purely syntactic element. In this context it is being used as an initializer.

Comment: "You should have received a warning about the char *doesnt = ... line" -- No, really, not. No compiler does that, fortunately.

Comment: @JimBalter g++ does: "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’". That's not quite a C compiler, but I wasn't making it up :)

Comment: Right, this is a C question (and answer), not C++.

Comment: @JimBalter I edited the answer to explain how you get the warning from `gcc`. So much for the "No compiler does that", I guess...

Comment: Thanks for the edit. No compiler does it in a default configuration, as that would lead to many warnings for legacy and common C code. "You should have received ..." is quite different from "You can make the compiler provide ...". And the details are still wrong: the compiler doesn't copy anything to `works`, although it might generate code that does so if `works` is on the stack -- but whether what it copies is writable is irrelevant since it isn't accessible. And `doesnt` may or may not point to non-writable memory -- some systems don't even have such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

The types `char[]` and `char *` are quite similar, so you are right about that.  The difference lies in what happens when objects of the types are initialized.  Your object `works`, of type `char[]`, has 128 bytes of variable storage allocated for it on the stack.  Your object `doesnt`, of type `char *`, *has no storage on the stack.*

Where exactly the string of `doesnt` is stored is not specified by the C standard, but most likely it is stored in a nonmodifiable data segment loaded when your program is loaded for execution.  This isn't variable storage.  Thus the segfault when you try to vary it.

Comment: "The difference lies" -- There are other, significant, differences between arrays and pointers. The issue here really isn't about that, but about the fact that doesnt points to a string constant, and the standard says that the results of modifying it are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

This allocates 128 bytes on the stack, and uses the name `works` to refer to its address:

```
char works[128];
```

So `works` is a pointer to writable memory.

This creates a string literal, which is in read-only memory, and uses the name `doesnt` to refer to its address:

```
char * doesnt = "example2\0";
```

You can write data to `works`, because it points to writable memory.  You can't write data to `doesnt`, because it points to read-only memory.

Also, note that you don't have to end your string literals with `"\0"`, since all string literals implicitly add a zero byte to the end of the string.

Comment: No, `works` is an array object, not a pointer. (Its name decays to a pointer expression in most contexts.)

Comment: "This allocates 128 bytes on the stack" -- we don't know the storage class; it could be extern. And as Keith notes, arrays are not pointers. (One consequence is that `sizeof(works) != sizeof((char*)works)`).