# char * variable declaration

Tags: char, constants

I just want to verify I got this right.
The copy from sr to ds2 gives an error. Is this because ds2 is considered "const"??
Thanks and hope this isn't a bore.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *sr = "Hello World";
    char *ds1 = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char *ds2 = "12345678901234567890";

    // This statement works just fine
    printf("%s\n", strcpy(ds1, sr));

    // This gives error
    strcpy(ds2, sr);


    printf("%s\n", ds2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar post

[difference between char* and char[] with strcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254953/difference-between-char-and-char-with-strcpy)

When you do this

```
char *ds2 = "12345678901234567890";
```

the compiler leaves the pointer pointing to a non-writable memory region.

With this line

```
// This gives error
   strcpy(ds2, sr);
```

You are trying to do an strcpy into the non-writable memory.

You should also have a free for each malloc as you are allocating memory but not de-allocating it.

Comment: Excellent - thought something like that. Yes, I know I should have a free(). (Trying to get back on the horse after 25yrs off).I appreciate your time and assistance. Best.